# Cannot retrieve Converted Value into TextBox WinForm c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**OverView Of Problem**

I have created a method which converts the input of a `TextBox` into TitleCase after the mouse looses focus. I have now encapsulated it into a seperate static class, 'Utillity', with all of my other buisness logic which are used widely in the project. My issue is that since  encapsulation my method does not seem to want to return back any data to the WinForm. After debugging, I found that the value was infact being passsed to the 'Uttility' Class, then being converted, however when it was being passed back, the value was the same as before conversion.

**Method in Utillity Class**

```
public static bool ToTitle(string s)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]");   // regex to change user input into Title Case.

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || (!s.Any(char.IsDigit)))
            // validate that the input is not a char or or null
            {
                s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInf‌​‌​o.ToTitleCase(s.ToLow‌​er());

                //MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value, no special chars or leaving this blank!!!!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            { return true; }

        }
```

**Code from Validating class.**

```
private void txt_SurName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Utillity.ToTitle(txt_SurName.Text);
                txt_SurName.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        }
```

What I think the issue is that because there is allready data in the `TextBox`, it assumes nothing has happend and the var 's' is left in the Utillity Class and not proeperly passed back. I had it working  If somone could help I would be very gratefull.

The only way I could get it to work was to force the conversion in each `Validating Event`, as follows which I know is very bad practise:

```
txt_SurName.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInf‌​‌​o.ToTitleCase(txt_SurName.Text.ToLow‌​er());
```

Because all this is doing is converting it inside the WinForm Class, Making the 'Utillity' class Redundant.

Comment: You're not utilizing the string `s` you get in your `ToTitle` method. You have to assign it to the `txt_SurName.Text` property again.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, as the value is just stuck in the Utillity Class. Should I assign the Value in `s` to the `txt_SurName.Text`   in side the `WinForm` Class?

Comment: How would i assign the value again from `s` to `txt_Surname` again?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txt_SurName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // You need to assign the changed text back to the control!
            txt_SurName.Text = Utillity.ToTitle(txt_SurName.Text);
            txt_SurName.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

Comment: That won't do, because in OP's code the `Utility.ToTitle` method returns `bool` and not the converted string.

Comment: Solved!!  with a mixture of the above posts. I had to change my return type however to string, which wasnt so bad as i could just reutnr the string to the TextBox.